# Android Application Project errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

recently I switched from Standard Eclipse to Eclipse Java EE due to it being better for android developers as I understood.
But the moment i changed I started having a lot of code problems, I'm building a project without doing anything and it comes up built with errors, I then built the app again and it solved itself, but later on the XML file started acting out, he tells me after "version" there supposed to be quotes at the "1.0" and there are, I'm seriously lost... problems keep stacking one another for no clear reason.

Comment: what if you try: **android:versionCode="1"** and **android:versionName="1.14.01.12 a"**? I use such values in my Manifest file.

Comment: Update all the android plug ins. Plus clean your project.

Comment: "recently I switched from Standard Eclipse to Eclipse Java EE due to it being better for android developers as I understood" -- I know of nobody making that recommendation.

Comment: Assuming the XML file you are referring to is AndroidManifest.xml, when you say "version" do you mean `versionCode` or `versionName`? The first is an integer so if you've put "1.0" there it will show an error.

Comment: @CommonsWare I cannot say that I prefer Eclipse for java EE, but it is true that some people recommends it. For instance, the book (as well known as yours) **Android Application Development in 24 Hours** from **Sams Teach Yourself** at least in the first edition says:
`If this is your first time using Eclipse, you’ll probably want to choose the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. This version of the Eclipse IDE includes the Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT) plug-in and the optional Web Tools Platform (WTP).`